# Google Drive api returns 500 internal error while listing and downloading large number of files

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

```
9/17/2013 3:04 PM Error: Google.GoogleApiRequestException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Internal Error [500]
Errors [
    Message[Internal Error] Location[ - ] Reason[internalError] Domain[global]
]

    at Google.Apis.Requests.Request.AsyncRequestResult.GetResponse()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.GetResponse()
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Fetch()
```

I tried to download 15GB of files with each file size is 2MB with the page size 100. After downloading 1500 files, the above error appeared. Is it a bug in API? Please help.
Note: I am reviving tokens properly.

Comment: There has been several issues with page tokens recently? Are you able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes! Very much reproducible. I never downloaded the entire 15 GB of 2mb files Successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation [suggests implementing an exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) in response to a 500 internal error.

Here is an example [retry helper class](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/13/a-retry-helper-class-with-exponential-backoff/) that you can use.